# Find work done by $F = \langle x,y,xz-y\rangle$ along $C:$ line segment from $A(0,0,0) $ to $B(2,1,2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find work done by $F = \langle x,y,xz-y\rangle$ along $C:$ line
>   segment from $A(0,0,0) $ to $B(2,1,2)$

$AB =\langle 2 , 1, 2\rangle$

Let $x=2t$
$ \; \; y =t \; \;  z=2t$

$\int_{c}^{} F.dR = \int_{c}^{} xdx + ydy + (xz-y)dz = \int_{0}^{1} 8t^2 + 3t = 25/6$

Is this correct ? Answer given on the back of my book is different. It says no work done. I don't see how?

Comment: First of all, it should be $3t$ in the integrand, not $2t$.

Comment: It is $8t^2+3t$.

Comment: I fixed it. But it is still not zero. Is my parametrisation ok ?

Comment: I also want to ask is it possible to have a non conservative force $F$ that does zero work on a closed curve ? I mean does zero work implies the force is conservative or not ?

Comment: @SoLo see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force#Mathematical_description

Comment: @MyGlasses is my answer above alright?

Comment: yes to me. $\dfrac{25}{6}$